# How to change the colormap of Seabron 2D histogram?

Tags: python, seaborn

I'm using Seaborn to make a 2D histogram. However, I cannot change the colormap. The existing parameters `palette` and `color` are not designed for 2D histogram. I'm looking for a parameter like `cmap` in `plt.hist2d()`.

And I have tried using `plt.hist2d()` as well. However, one dimension of my data is categorical, while the other is numerical. Thus, the `plt.hist2d()` reports error saying:

> TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can use `sns.histplot(data=..., x=..., y=..., color='red')` and seaborn will use different shades of that color.  Or you can use `sns.histplot(data=..., x=..., y=..., cmap='inferno')` to use a colormap.    If that doesn't work,  you could try to create a reproducible example to show what you tried and how that's different from what you expected.

Answer (score 1):

You can either change the base color via `color=...`. Or set a colormap via `cmap=...`.

Here is an example using the tips dataset:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(12, 5))

sns.histplot(data=tips, x='tip', y='day', color='purple', ax=ax1)
ax1.set_title("using 'color=...'")

sns.histplot(data=tips, x='tip', y='day', cmap='inferno', ax=ax2)
ax2.set_title("using 'cmap=...'")

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.histplot with cmap]

PS: In [sns.histplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.histplot.html)'s documentation, `cmap` is referenced indirectly as

```
Other keyword arguments are passed to one of the following matplotlib functions:
     ...
     matplotlib.axes.Axes.pcolormesh() (bivariate)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I can use the parameter `cmap` now. However, when I was asking this question, I tried using `cmap='jet'`, but it gave me the error message `ValueError: No.`. Now I tried other colormaps, like `'rainbow'`, it worked. Do you know what's wrong with `'jet'`?

Comment: `jet` has [a very bad reputation](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2014/10/16/how-bad-is-your-colormap/) as it mistakenly draws attention to a yellow highlight. As such, Seaborn's author strongly dislikes it.  Nowadays, [`turbo`](https://ai.googleblog.com/2019/08/turbo-improved-rainbow-colormap-for.html)is recommended as an alternative for a colormap that is both rainbow-like and without strange highlights.

Comment: Thanks! That is interesting to know. And thanks for the recommendation for `turbo`.